# Using vim for LaTeX versus something else?

Tags: vim, latex

For those that regularly use vim and that also regularly use LaTeX, do you recommend using vim for LaTeX? If not, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [LaTeX-Suite](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=475) it makes writing LaTeX very easy within vim.  I've tried other alternatives but always come back to vim.

Comment: Thanks, especially for mentioning that you've tried other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

**Obligatory answer:** `emacs`. With `auctex`.

Not that there is anything wrong with `vi` if your tastes run that way.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it, but don't have time to learn emacs right now. I was particularly targeting the intersection of vim users and LaTeX users.

Answer (score 1):

I've used vim for both writing articles and presentations (through [beamer-latex](http://latex-beamer.sourceforge.net/)) and I am personally very satisfied.

Couple the powerful editing capabilities of vim with the comfort of the many macros, templates, compiling support and various features of the [vim-latex plugin](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php) and, if you are confortable with vim, you will hardly find any better environment for latex editing.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to consider beamer-latex for my next presentation.